# Typescript Generics class

Tags: generics, typescript

I was practicing with Generics classes and I found this, maybe it's normal behavior, if it is a normal behavior that what happens to `public testT : T;`

```
class Punto<T> extends Base{
    ..//
    public testT : T;

    constructor(test: string){
        super();
        ..//  
    }
}

..//

let punto: Punto; <- this does not work (I expected that)
```

> Generic type 'Punto' requires 1 type argument(s). class Punto

```
let punto: Punto<number>;                <- this I work (I expected that)

let puntoI = new Punto('test');          <- why this works, what happens to public testT : T;

let puntoI = new Punto<number>('test');  <- this I work (I expected that)
```

---

### Update:

excuse my English and I hope you now understand better, after doing a few tests, I saw some differences.

```
class Base{   
    constructor(private id: string){
        
    }   
    print(){
        console.log(this.id);
    }
}

class DSimple<T> extends Base{
    constructor(public varT: T,id: string){
        super(id);
    }
}

let oBase: Base      = new Base('oBase');
let uSimple: DSimple = new DSimple(oBase,'der'); //<-- Now no work (I expected that)

    Generic type 'DSimple<T>' requires 1 type argument(s).
    class DSimple<T>

let unoSimple: DSimple<Base> = new DSimple(oBase,'derivada1'); //<-- work (I expected that)
```

In my other `.ts` file for test to which I referred to earlier

```
class Base{
   
}

class Punto extends Base{

    constructor(test: string){
        super();      
    }  
}

class Punto3<T extends Base>{

    constructor(public gene: T, test: string){
   
    }   
}
..//

let puntoInicializado = new Punto('test');
let punto3 = new Punto3(puntoInicializado,'test punto 3'); <-- this work
```

> Maybe it's because infers types yeah

because it behaves differently when using

```
let punto3 = new Punto3(puntoInicializado,'test punto 3'); <-- this work
let uSimple: DSimple = new DSimple(oBase,'der'); //<-- Now no work (I expected that)
```

- `let punto3                 =..`    --- work
- `let uSimple: DSimple       =..`    --- no work
- `let uSimple: DSimple<Base> =..`    --- work

You have any explanation? Why the point one inferred and the point two not, and must be used for this case point three."Maybe it's a terrible question sorry if it is."

Comment: Your code is a bit abbreviated, so difficult to say, but perhaps it works because T is inferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your question is related to so called 'Type Argument Inference' and well covered in the following section of the typescript specification: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4152-type-argument-inference)

[EDIT]

1. Point #1: `let punto` - works due to type inference.
2. Point #2: `let uSimple: DSimple` - does not work as it violates typescript specification for type references, as explicitly stated here: [type argument lists](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#362-type-argument-lists)
3. Point #3: `let uSimple: DSimple<Base>` - works as it has correct type reference to generic type (for more info see link above and also [type references](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#382-type-references))

Comment: I give you +1 just because the first time I did not explain well, I update, sorry for my English and thanks for your time

Comment: English is not native for me either. No need to be sorry. Check my update - I added more info. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line (`let punto: Punto;`), you *declare* a variable's signature, so compiler makes you to specify correct type, otherwise it's a compilation error.

In the third line (`let puntoI = new Punto('test');`), you just *assign* a value to the variable, so compiler tries to determine variable's type, but if it fails, the type defaults to `any`. I can assume that `puntoI` is either `any` or `Punto<any>`, don't know for sure.